# Angular Http request take more time than in postman

Tags: angular, rest, postman, httpclient

I have a rest web service and I try to call it in my angular application (using httpClient) but when I open the network console I find that the time my request take is higher than the time it takes to make the same request in postman (by more than 30%) is there an explanation and how to resolve it (if possible)

Comment: It's likely CORS related. Postman doesn't send a preflight request.

Comment: Angular adds additional overhead to the request. This overhead includes things like serializing the request body, adding security headers, and handling the response.

Use a profiler to identify the specific part of your Angular application's code that is causing the bottleneck. Once you have identified the bottleneck, you can try to optimize it.

Comment: has you an [Interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http-intercept-requests-and-responses) that could cause the problem?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler thank you for responding , i will check my CORS

Comment: @ChintanDhokai thank you for responding , is it possible to provide more info on how to use profiler to identifie the botetlneck

Comment: @Eliseo thank you for responding , i do have an intercept that juste redirect my request to the correct host , can that have an effect on my request time ?

Comment: I don't know if the "bottleneck" is in this. check if you're accidentally redirected severals times or only one (only one can not be a problem)